# GWT Tree dynamically

Tags: gwt, tree

I want to a generate a tree in GWT using string parsing.
my question is, I have some string from server,using these lines I want to create tree in GWT.

The tree look as see picture

[image]

How can I create the tree in gwt using for loop or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

use a  [Tree](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwTree) or [CellTree](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree) and split the strings with `string.split()`

```
String[] tmp = string.split(".");
Arrays.asList(tmp);
```

Comment: here every line is a separate string. ie, admin.group, admin.report, so totally i have 10 lines. and I have split every string with ".", now I got 2 or 3 strings for every line. then with this I have to generate                 for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { // here result.length 10
                       
                         System.out.println("result[i] " + result[i]); 
                        splits = result[i].split("\\.", 1);
                        treeItems = new TreeItem[splits.length];
                    }

Comment: update your question with the relevant code and explain what you tried and what is not working

Comment: hello Tobika, see the link  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_tree_widget.htm ... the TreeItems are to be created dynamically thats all, because here we know, how many TreeItems are to be added, but my case dont know how many tree items are to created. according to lines from server i have to create treeItem

Comment: it doenst matter if you know how many items are created. just use a `Map` and create your `TreeItems` dynamically

Comment: Thanks, I will try, if   you already done, please put your code I will check with you which one is feasible